# Extend the MembershipUser class with a custom membership provider

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I require some more fields related to users. So whether its good idea to extend MembershipUser class or to create separate class that has relationship (foreign key) with MembershipUser class UserID?

Comment: Did you check out the many variaions on this question that you can see in the "Related" list to the right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extend Membership API, MembershipUser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538059/extend-membership-api-membershipuser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a thin line between what is considered to be Membership-related, and what is considered to be Profile-Related.

If the field you are referencing are not really membership/account specific, I would implement a different way of dealing with them other than the Membership Provider.

Solutions inlclude: The profile provider; Your own artifacts.